# How can I change value of html element based off of user's input?

Tags: javascript, html

A list item as shown line 22, is by default "panthers 20". Based off some input from the user, I am trying to overwrite "panthers" to whatever the user inputs.

I am familiar java/c#/c++. But web development is very new to me, so I seem to lack the understanding of the syntax.

I've tried figuring this out by reading tutorials, but all the different combinations of syntax I tried, didnt work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script> //used when user enters in value and submits
      function showInput() {
          document.getElementById('display').innerHTML =
                      document.getElementById("user_input").value;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
<body>
  <form>
    <label><b>Enter a Message</b></label>
    <input type="text" name="message" id="user_input">
  </form>

  <input type="submit" onclick="showInput();"><br/>
  <label>Your input: </label>
  <p><span id="display"></span></p>


  <li class="team"><span id="lbltipAddedComment">panthers</span><span class="score">20</span></li>


  <script> //attempting to change the value of panthers to the users input
  document.getElementById("lbltipAddedComment").innerHTML = display.value;
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

If user inputs rams, the list item "team" should say rams 20, instead of panthers 20.

```
document.getElementById("lbltipAddedComment").innerHTML = display.value;
```

seems to be the issue. Using `display.value` outputs `undefined20` and using `display` outputs `[object HTMLSpanElement]20`

Comment: "display" is not an input element. If you want to get the values of non input elements you have to use `innerHTML`. Try using "`display.innerHTML`"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to put your javascript code that manipulates the DOM at the bottom of the HTML file. This way the DOM can load first, then the javascript can take effect.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <label><b>Enter a Message</b></label>
    <input type="text" name="message" id="user_input">
  </form>

  <input type="submit" onclick="showInput();"><br/>
  <label>Your input: </label>
  <p><span id="output-section"></span></p>


  <li class="team"><span id="lbltipAddedComment">panthers</span> <span class="score">20</span></li>


  <script>
    //attempting to change the value of panthers to the users input
    function showInput() {
      var userInput = document.getElementById("user_input").value;
      document.getElementById('output-section').innerHTML = userInput;
      document.getElementById("lbltipAddedComment").innerHTML = userInput;
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @tonytone No problem! If you're satisfied with this answer please click the checkmark underneath the voting buttons to accept it.

Comment: ah okay, first time posting